# Como obter somente a data, sem a hora, de um DateTime?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

Convertendo um campo utilizando `ToDateTime` ele traz a data e a hora.

```
parcelamento.data_vencimento = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["data_vencimento"]);
```

Existe alguma conversão direta para trazer somente a data sem a hora?

Comment: Qual é o tipo de `parcelamento.data_vencimento`? Isto é importante para saber como você precisa obter a data. Até tem outras coisas que precisariam ser analisadas pra ver se pode usar o `Convert.ToDateTime`, eu tenho quase certeza que isto é um erro. Fazer o que foi sugerido na resposta abaixo não muda nada: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TX6n3c

Comment: Se me responder isso, eu melhoro a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado já deu certo..

Comment: Mas seria bom esclarecer para poder ajudar outras pessoas. Aproveite e dê uma olhada no [tour] para conhecer mais como o site funciona.

Comment: A minha variavel data_vencimento esta no formato DateTime, e por padrão o gridview, ao renderizar, chama o .ToString() do campo.
Eu tive que mudar esse comportamento utilizando o datastringformat no próprio campo da gridview

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

Tudo depende do tipo de `parcelamento.data_vencimento`. Ele é um `DateTime`? Então não tem nada para ser feito, se o tipo diz que deve ter uma data e uma hora, é isso que terá nele. O que você pode fazer quando precisar apresentar é pegar só a data, sem o horário, mas isto é questão de apresentação.

Não confunda dado armazenado com dado a ser apresentado. São duas coisas distintas. Dado apresentado sempre é uma *string* e pode estar no formato que achar melhor. Tanto não importa que a outra resposta não faz nada útil, [veja](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TX6n3c).

O `parcelamento.data_vencimento` é `string`? Duvido. Se for, vai ter dificuldade de manipulá-lo. Se precisa só para apresentar mesmo, então `.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` resolve.

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine(ToDateTime("03/25/2015").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/loMRiL). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mH3e2p). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/DateTime/Format.cs).

Quase sempre armazenar só a data é um erro e precisaria ter um bom motivo para fazer isto. Os motivos que vejo as pessoas "terem" para usar um tipo só com a data costumam ser furados. Se quiser mesmo fazê-lo, aconselho usar uma biblioteca que faça isto bem, como a [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) do Jon Skeet.

Me parece que tem alguma estrutura só com a data em algum lugar do .Net ou alguma biblioteca ligada a ele, mas para uso bem específico, provavelmente banco de dados, não para uso geral, por isso não é fácil de achar.

Se for corajoso, crie uma estrutura para isto.

Dependo do que for usar precisaria analisar como construir uma data nova, se precisa passar os membros da data isoladamente, se deve passar uma *string*, se pode ser formatada, se pode passar um `DateTime` para ele converter.

Outra coisa que deve analisar é se pode usar o `Convert.ToDateTime()`. Esta não é uma boa opção para pegar *strings* externas que você não possui controle total.

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo que você dê uma olhada na documentação da `struct` [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) na MSDN.

Mas o que você deseja pode ser obtido através da propriedade `Date` de uma instância de `DateTime`. Essa propriedade retorna um `DateTime` que possui apenas a parte da data com as horas zeradas (00:00:00 ou 12:00:00 AM).

```
parcelamento.data_vencimento = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["data_vencimento"]).Date;
```

Answer (score -2):

Simples, para pegar apenas a data é só usar a função DateValue.

Exemplo no .NET

```
Dim MyDate
MyDate = DateValue("#1/3/2024 7:26:00 AM#")
Debug.Print(MyDate) '"#1/3/2024"
```

Em c# tente algo como:

```
MyDate = new DateValue();
MyDate.value = "#1/3/2024 7:26:00 AM#";
Console.WriteLine(MyDate); '"#1/3/2024"
```